# Two sets specified in the function have different dimensionality

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008, ssas-2012

I have a basic query and having trouble understand exactly what this error means.

```
Select {[Dim Date].[Date].[Date],[Measures].[Quantity]} on columns
from 
[AcoEdsv]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do so far? What should this SELECT show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not error, but wrong query.

I believe error is:

`Members, tuples or sets must use the same hierarchies in the function`.

In other words, `Set` and `Member` used as a `Set`.

`[Dim Date].[Date].[Date]` - it's a set of `Level Date`'s members. E.g. {2/1/2015, 2/2/2015, 2/3/2015} and so on.

`[Measures].[Quantity]` - it's a member `Quantity` of special dimension `Measures`.

Here is list of fails in your query and possible solutions:

1) `[Measures].[Quantity]` should be on another axis (e.g. `, [Measures].[Quantity] on rows`)

```
Select {[Dim Date].[Date].[Date]} on columns
,[Measures].[Quantity] on rows
from
[AcoEdsv]
```

2) Or you're trying to use aggregation function without determining
    itself. Let's say SUM:

```
with member [Measures].[Test]
as SUM({[Dim Date].[Date].[Date]},[Measures].[Quantity])

Select {[Dim Date].[Date].[Date]} on columns
,[Measures].[Test] on rows
from 
[AcoEdsv]
```